# Using localStorage to retain stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons and I am able to change my stylesheet once I click on these buttons. However once I refresh or when I go to the next page on my website the stylesheet reverts back to the original and does not stay how the user set it. I have been searching for similar examples but only found those using cookies and I wanted to know how this could be done using localStorage.
Thanks in advance...

```
<script>
  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
  }
</script>

<div class="change">
  <h6>Change Stylesheet</h6>
  <button onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/style2.css')">Dark</button>
  <button onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/style.css')">Light</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sure - you should try writing that part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could use the following:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentStyleSheet', 'css/style.css');
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
     document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
     localStorage.setItem('currentStyleSheet', sheet);
}
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('currentStyleSheet'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have replaced it with the original script and the buttons still do work however when i reload the page the style is not retained...